# Creating a detail view with get_context_data grabbing data from url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am able to push a string value, `title` from the `book` object selected to the url to display a detail view now with the following EDITS:

fixed the missing `%}`  tag and added the missing app_name = 'books' to fix the `{% url 'book_detail' book.title` to `{% url 'books:book_detail" book.title %}`

views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_data'] = Book.objects.all()
        context['books_by_john'] = Books.objects.filter(author = 'John')

        return context
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'books'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('login/index/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('login/index/<str:key>', views.BookView.as_view(), name ='book_detail')
```

index.html

```
<ul>
    {% for book in book_data %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'books:book_detail' book.title %}"> {{book.title}} - {{book.name}} - {{book.author}}</a> </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now how would i be able to use the value in this url to display only data from the specific book in my detail view? so it would do something like this

views.py

```
class BookView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/book_info.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_description'] = Book.objects.filter(title=<title from url>)
        return context
```

EDIT2: Eventually i'm going to need multiple data sets to pull from in the IndexView, if so should i use listview? and how would i use multiple querysets in a listview

Answer (score 3):

Your template tag is malformed; you're missing the closing `%}`. So it's not being parsed as a tag at all.

It should be:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.title %}"> {{book.title}} - {{book.name}} - {{book.author}}</a> </li>
```

For your other question, you should use a more appropriate view to subclass; in your case, DetailView would do exactly what you want. (And your index view should be based on ListView, which would remove the need for your `get_context_data` method altogether.)

Comment: For using the ListView, would i use the `get_queryset` method instead?

Comment: I am eventually going to need to break down the books by author in the index view so i will need to be able to use something like Books.objects.filter(author="<name">`) to be able to list all the books by a specific author in the index view template.. so all the books will be shown but organized by author

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the proper way to do this (by using TemplateViews instead of ListView, and DetailViews). But since i am going to eventually be using multiple data sets from multiple models for my IndexView i just stuck with TemplateView. If someone can explain why this is a bad idea i would greatly appreciate it

But i solved this problem by adding `slug` instead of `str` to my url path like so

```
path('login/index/<slug:title>', views.BookView.as_view(), name ='book_detail')
```

and adding `context['book_description'] = Book.objects.filter(title = self.kwargs['title'])` to my BookView like this

```
class BookView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/book_info.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_description'] = Book.objects.filter(title = self.kwargs['title'])
    return context
```

I was able create the data set to filter the `Book` model through the title in the url in my book_detail.html template

```
 {% for x in book_description %}

    <li>{{ x.summary }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```